# Web Service PHP com INNER JOIN

Tags: php, angularjs, json, web-service, api

Estou criando API para consumo em aplicativos Ionic, mas estou penando à 2 semanas em uma dessas api's, onde eu relaciono dados em mais de uma tabela com inner join. Tentei fazer como no meu sistema php, onde eu adiciono os itens no banco, alguém poderia me ajudar a concluir essa api?

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

$db = new mysqli("mysql.meudominio.com.br", "nome", "senha", "nome");

$sql = $db->query("SELECT refeicao.nome, refeicao.id FROM refeicao_refeicao AS refeicao
            INNER JOIN refeicao_alimento AS opcao
            INNER JOIN alimentos_refeicao AS cardapio
            WHERE cardapio.id_refeicao = refeicao.id
            AND cardapio.id_alimentos = opcao.id
            GROUP BY refeicao.id");

        $saida = '{"refeicao":';
            $saida .= "[";

            while($r = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                if($saida != "["){$saida = ", ";}
                $saida.= '{"nome":"'.$r[0].'",';
                $saida.= '"id_refeicao":"'.$r[1].'"}';
                //$saida.= '"senha":"'.$r["senha"].'"}';

                $id_refeicao = $r[1];


                $sql2 = $db->query ("SELECT refeicao_alimento.nome
                    FROM refeicao_alimento 
                    INNER JOIN refeicao_refeicao
                    INNER JOIN alimentos_refeicao
                    WHERE alimentos_refeicao.id_alimentos = refeicao_alimento.id
                    AND alimentos_refeicao.id_refeicao = $id_refeicao
                    GROUP BY refeicao_alimento.id");

                while($sr = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                        if($saida != "["){$saida = ", ";}
                        $saida.= '{"nome":"'.$r["nome"].'"}';

                }; 

            };
        $saida .= "}"; echo json_encode($saida); ?>
```

Eu precisaria que ele imprimisse um json dessa api, algo assim para 7 refeições diferentes:

```
{almoco: [
    {"Opção 1": "Até 5 colheres de sopa de arroz integral ou qualquer outro carboidrato + proteína (Carne, ovos, peixe, frutos do mar, frango, o tanto que quiser até saciar"},
    {"Opção 2": "Proteína (Carne, ovos, peixe, frutos do mar, frango, o tanto que quiser até saciar + couve flor gratinada (ver receita) + arroz integral + salada verde à vontade." },
    {"Opção 3": "Três colheres de sopa de purê de batata doce ou de abóbora (80 gramas) com filé de peixe ou qualquer outra proteína (Carne, ovos, peixe, frutos  do mar, frango, o tanto que quiser até saciar) + até 4 colheres de sopa de legumes cozidos + salada verde à vontade."},    
    {"Opção 4": "Um pedaço de 150g de torta funcional de frango (ver receita ) + salada verdade à vontade."},
    {"Opção 5": "Arroz integral + proteína (Carne, ovos, peixe, frutos do mar, frango, o tanto que quiser até saciar) + até 1 concha rasa de feijão + salada verde à vontade. Usar esta opção somente uma vez na semana."},    
    {"Opção 6": "Strogonoff fit de carne ou frango (ver receita) + até 5 colheres de arroz integral + salada verde à vontade."},
    {"Opção 7": "Suflê de frango (ver receita) + purê de batata doce ou abóbora + salada à vontade."},
    {"Importante": "É obrigatório o carboidrato no almoço. E aqui são opções de como usar as proteínas e carboidratos, mas podem utilizar de outra forma se quiserem."}
```

]}

E para o usuário:

Café da Manhã

Lista de Opções:

Uma fatia de pãozinho funcional (ver receita) + ovos mexidos + uma fatia de queijo + chá em sachê ou café com adoçante.

Crepioca (ver receita) com recheio de Requeijão light e orégano + chá em sache ou café com adoçante.

Pão de queijo de frigideira (ver receita) + chá em sachê ou café com adoçante.

Até 5 bolachas de arroz integral + ovos inteiros (tanto que precisar) + uma fatia de queijo + chá em sachê ou café com adoçante.

Pãozinho de batata doce (ver receita) + chá em sachê ou café com adoçante.

Um pedaço de bolo de cenoura (ver receita+ chá em sachê ou café com adoçante.

Um pedaço de bolo de banana (ver receita) + chá em sachê ou café com adoçante.

Mingau de aveia com banana e cacau.

Ovos (tanto que precisar) + uma fruta + 2 colheres de sopa de aveia.

Panqueca de banana ou coco (ver receita) com pasta de amendoim + chá em sache ou café com adoçante.

Almoço

Lista de Opções:

Até 5 colheres de sopa de arroz integral ou qualquer outro carboidrato + proteína (Carne, ovos, peixe, frutos do mar, frango, o tanto que quiser até saciar) + salada verde à vontade.

Proteína (Carne, ovos, peixe, frutos do mar, frango, até 200g) + couve flor gratinada (ver receita) + arroz integral + salada verde à vontade.

3 colheres de sopa de purê de batata doce ou de abóbora (80 gramas), com uma proteína (Carne, ovos, peixe, frutos do mar, frango, até 200g) + até 4 colheres de sopa de legumes cozidos + salada verde à vontade.

1 pedaço de torta funcional de frango (ver receita ) + salada verdade à vontade.

Arroz integral + proteína (Carne, ovos, peixe, frutos do mar, frango, o tanto que quiser até saciar)+ até 1 concha rasa de feijão + salada verde à vontade.

Strogonoff fit de carne ou frango (ver receita) + até 5 colheres de arroz integral + salada verde à vontade.

Suflê de frango (ver receita) + purê de batata doce ou abóbora + salada a vontade.

Comment: Voce cria apelidos para tabelas que nem possuem nomes de campos iguais, deixa de definir uma váriavel para seu vetor percorrer com while, não define os campos que irá percorrer, e criar JOIN com apelidos de tabela chamando campos que não estão no Select, ou seja, irá ficar anos e não ira funcionar, vou postar uma resposta mas não entendi lendo seu código diversas vezes quais os campos quer dar select, se falasse os campos e quais tabelas eles estão referentes seria ótimo. E outra, você percorre um while e define uma váriavel $r e ao invés de colocar nome de tabela coloca números

Answer (score 0):

```
query("SELECT * FROM refeicao_refeicao
            INNER JOIN refeicao_alimento ON refeicao_refeicao
            INNER JOIN alimentos_refeicao ON refeicao_refeicao
            WHERE cardapio.id_refeicao = refeicao.id
            AND cardapio.id_alimentos = opcao.id
            GROUP BY refeicao.id");
```

Tenta assim, se não der tente relacionar o id na tabela que esta dando o select por exemplo:

```
query("SELECT * FROM refeicao_refeicao
                INNER JOIN refeicao_alimento ON refeicao_refeicao.refeicao_alimento_id=refeicao_alimento.refeicao_alimento_id
                INNER JOIN alimentos_refeicao ON refeicao_refeicao.alimentos_refeicao_id=alimentos_refeicao.alimentos_refeicao_id
                WHERE cardapio.id_refeicao = refeicao.id
                AND cardapio.id_alimentos = opcao.id
                GROUP BY refeicao.id");
```

Assim ele vai ligar como uma chave estrangeira então sera necessario criar o id das demais tabelas inseridas com o inner join.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa mande um feed back do resultado :D

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem seu `JOIN` mas vou postar seu código com algumas coisas corrigidas, e se caso não funcionar comente o que esta acontencendo

Primeiro erro: Logo no começo você cria uma query na váriavel que está fazendo select, isto é errado, deveria primeiro fazer o select depois setar a query.

Segundo erro: cometido é definir apelidos para campos / tabelas que não possuem nome idêntico.

Terceiro erro: seu While define `mysqli_fetch_array` e você seta como parâmetro o `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, portanto mas um erro encontrado. Conflitando `ARRAY` com `ASSOC`

Quarto erro: Seu While está a percorrer tabelas mas você indica para o While que a váriavel `$r` ira percorrer número invés de tabela indicando `$r[0] e $r[1]` enquanto deveria informar o nome de uma tabela existente no banco de dados.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM REFEICAO_REFEICAO A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN REFEICAO_ALIMENTO B ON (A.ID = B.ID)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ALIMENTOS_REFEICAO C ON (B.ID = C.ID_ALIMENTOS) GROUP BY A.id ";

$resultado = $db->query($sql);

$valores = array();

if($resultado){

    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $valores['nome'] = $row['nome'];
        $valores['id_refeicao'] = $row['id_refeicao'];
        $valores['senha'] = $row['senha'];

        array_push($valores, $novo);
    }

} else {
    return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
}
    return json_encode($valores);
```